# Android toast message while inputing database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, toast

I'm currently developing an android app. I'm going to show toast message while inserting database in the same time. But unfortunately, the toast message did not show up. Here it is my code:

```
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
        Cursor c = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllContent();
        c.moveToLast();
        int count1=c.getCount();
            if(count1==0)
            {
                //value not present
                Toast.makeText(this, "Now Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                insertData();
            }
            else
            {
              //value present
            }
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

The insertData() is the method for inserting data to database. Anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Here it is the full code of my class:

```
package com.example.anagramslayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

 private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
 ImageButton LevelModule;
 ImageButton ExitModule;
 ImageButton HelpModule;
 ImageButton CreditModule;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //TextView listContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listview); //buat nampilin listview

      //init buttons
        LevelModule =  (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        LevelModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        ExitModule =  (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        ExitModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        HelpModule =  (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.help_button);
        HelpModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        CreditModule =  (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.credit_button);
        CreditModule.setOnClickListener(this);


        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        AppPreferences AppPref = new AppPreferences(this);

        //int x = AppPref.getScore();
        //TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        //t.setText(x);

        //checking values exists
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
        Cursor c = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllContent();
        c.moveToLast();
        int count1=c.getCount();
            if(count1==0)
            {
                //value not present
                Toast.makeText(this, "Now Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                insertData();
            }
            else
            {
              //value present
            }
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
        //end of checking value exists

        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
        //String contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll(); //buat nampilin listview
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();  
        //listContent.setText(contentRead);                //buat nampilin listview


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.play_button:
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, LevelList.class));
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.exit_button:
                 finish();
                 System.exit(0);
                break;
            case R.id.help_button:
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Help.class));
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.credit_button:
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Credit.class));
                finish();
                break;
             }
         }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    private void insertData() {
        //insert record
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("apel",      "Peal",         "the competitor of samsung", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_1");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("semangka",  "Game Sank",    "it's big and green", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_2");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("anggur",    "Run Gag",      "ferment it, it will become wine anggur run gag ferment it, it will become wine","0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_3");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("pisang",    "Gasp In",      "it's yellow and loved by minion", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_4");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("melon",     "Lemon",        "it's round, quite big, and green", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_5");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("alpukat",   "A Talk Up",    "it tastes plain. Usually, people make juice or ice drink from it", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_6");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("mangga",    "Gag Man",      "it's green. Sometimes, it tastes sweet or sour", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_7");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("cokelat",   "A Locket",     "its name is the same with its color", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_8");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("persik",    "Pikers",       "in japan, people call it momo fruit", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_9");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("salak",     "Ask La",       "its skin is like a snake skin", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_10");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("kurma",     "A Murk",       "you can find this fruit in california or midle east", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_11");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("durian",    "Run Aid",      "spike skinned fruit and it smells bad", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_12");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("cempedak",  "Packed Me",    "this fruit looks like a jackfruit", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_13");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("jambu",     "Um Jab",       "it cures scarlet fever", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_14");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("kelapa",    "Lake Pa",      "you usually will find this fruit in a beach", "0", "1", "com.example.anagramslayer:drawable/hint1_15");


        //end of database

        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
        //end of insert record

    }

}
```

Comment: post your full code. for displaying toast you need activity context. this refers to the current context.

Comment: Two things to consider: First, are you sure that count1 actually ever equals 0 and the Toast code gets executed? Second, are you performing this action off the Main Thread? Toast.show() will not work unless you're on the Main Thread.

Comment: MattDavis, First: yes it is. Because the insertData() is executed. So, that means the toast is suppose to be executed as well. Second, I put these code in the public void onCreate

Comment: @BobbyChandra paste your class code

Comment: I put the full code above

Comment: @BobbyChandra : probably if block is not executing so best way is use Log api to check control flow when statements executing

Comment: Put a break point at toast statement, run in debug mode. When breakpoint is reached, step through statements and see what happens. If call to `insertData()` takes more time than toast's duration, that might cause problem.

Comment: have you debug you code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do the data insert in an AsynTask class, in this case, the dataInsert method will not occupy the resource when you try to show the Toast message